# Boot repair hanging on purge kernels then reinstall last kernel

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm running 14.04.3 from live cd trying to move grub from a failing hard drive that had windows on it that's no longer used (sda).  I plan on taking out this hard drive when I'm done.  I'm trying to move the bootloader/grub to my good hard drive with my current ubuntu installation (sdb).  I got the partition with ubuntu (sdb1) shrunk and prepended a new partition to with ext4 file system (sdb3).  I used boot repair to default to sdb1 for the OS and to put grub on sdb3.

It was going well until it hit:

`Purge kernels then reinstall last kernel sdb1 (ins).  This may require several minutes.`

It has been stuck at this for over an hour.  Not sure what to do here, if its safe to stop it, or to restart (either through GUI or Alt+SysRq+REISUB).

Comment: Also here is my boot info report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14146982

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up cancelling this and mounting the new drive, and chroot into the mounted drive and running the commands from there.